# NSXMLParser not working in UICollectionView [OBJ-C]

Tags: objective-c, uicollectionview, nsxmlparser

For some reason my xml parse won't run, the log NSLog(@"topic at collection View:%@",self.topic);
is showing the correct value, but none of my parsing methods are running. I've used NSXMLParser in multiple other View controllers and I have not had any issues until now. The biggest difference is that this is in a UICollectionView, I didn't think that would effect it but I can't see where else it could be going wrong.
Couple Notes:

1. the url isn't ******* i omitted it for privacy
2. The method [self runXMLParse]; is in viewDidLoad
3. My biggest question here is in regards to whether a UICollectionViewController would prevent the parse from running
4. None of the other logs besides NSLog(@"topic at collection View:%@",self.topic); are running

   ```
   -(void)runXMLParse{
   //runs the parse
   NSLog(@"topic at collection View:%@",self.topic);
   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://***********/topicMembers.php?topic=%@",self.topic]];
   parser=[[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
   [parser setDelegate:self];
   [parser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:NO];
   [parser parse];
   }
   -(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString             *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {
   element = elementName;
   NSLog(@"parser called");
   if ([element isEqualToString:@"Members"]) {
       item    = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
       memberUpdate  = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
       NSLog(@"Members Rec");
   }

   }//define variables to extract info from xml doc
   - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string {
   //search for tags
   NSLog(@"Step 1");
   if ([element isEqualToString:@"username"]) {
   [memberUpdate appendString:string];
   NSLog(@"Username found");
   }


   }

   - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString     *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {
   NSLog(@"3");
   if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"username"]) {
   [item setObject:memberUpdate forKey:@"member"];
   [MemberList addObject:[memberUpdate copy]];//The problem lies in add objects
   NSLog(@"member update ::%@",memberUpdate);

   }}
   ```

Comment: Do you have a sample XML? Maybe it's just a parse error you can't see cause you didn't implement the parseErrorOccurred: method

Comment: Yes it is throwing an error, about to investigate a little more,P.S the XML is in proper format(I know this because I ran it in the Postman restclient and it is showing just fine)

Comment: Hey @Imotep you were right, I had a line of whitespace before the start of my php code. It didn't even occur to me that that could be the problem, please respond with this so I can give you best answer

Comment: Thanks, enjoy your parsing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be a parse error.

Try to implement the `parserErrorOccurred:` method to know more.